# React native animation.reset doesn't reset the animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have an translate animation. Animation is executed on component load and after the animation is complete I am trying to reset the animation. However the animation reset doesn't do anything.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import {Animated, SafeAreaView, View} from 'react-native'

const App = () => {
    const value = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY({x: 0, y: 0})).current

    useEffect(() => {
        const translateAnim = Animated.timing(value, {
            toValue: {x: 100, y: 100},
            duration: 1000,
            useNativeDriver: false,
        })
        translateAnim.start(result => {
            if (result.finished) {
                translateAnim.reset()
            }
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Animated.View style={value.getLayout()}>
                <View
                    style={{
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        borderRadius: 50,
                        backgroundColor: 'red',
                    }}></View>
            </Animated.View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default App
```

Snack Expo link: https://snack.expo.io/Wj5zswB-s

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `.start()` after `.reset()`. That replays the animation. If you call `.start()` after it finishes playing without resetting, then nothing happens. So seems like `reset()` does do something but for some reason it doesn't get reflected unless you call `.start()`.